# Wrong Y-axis direction on node select and mouse move in Vivagraph.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, rendering, vivagraphjs

I made a simple graph using vivagraph.js and it webglGraphics and added images on nodes. But nodes move incorrect on Y axis. When I select node 
 and move mouse up image moves down. How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

I changed y position to negative and now it works fine for images but when I add text node, node moves in opposite direction to my mouse

line: 5413 = > changed

```
pos.y = ui.position.y;    to=>   pos.y = -ui.position.y;
```